# Why I'm getting a <pending> Promise?

Tags: node.js, async-await, readfile

```
const fsPromises = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");

const getCities = async (country) => {
  const cities = [];

  try {
    const data = await fsPromises.readFile(
      path.join(__dirname, "countries-and-cities.csv"),
      "utf8"
    );
    const records = data.split("\n");
    for (const record of records) {
      if (record.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(country.toLowerCase())) {
        cities.push(record.split(",")[1]);
      }
    }

    return cities;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const result = getCities("United States");
console.log(result);
```

I'm trying to read a csv file and then get the cities of a given country in an array. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if I console.log inside the loop the data is there.

Answer (score 1):

Because the promise is still pending

You wanted to wait for it like that:

```
getCities("United States").then(result => console.log(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to await for your async function:

```
const result = await getCities("United States");
```

Comment: You can't do `await` outside of an async function right?

Comment: Now it's possible, you need to put the next line in your package json:
"type": "module"

Comment: That´s true, I assumed that this was an example to picture the problem. If you would need t call it from that level I would just go with an Immediately Invoked Function Expression but `(async function () {
  const result = await getCities("United States");
  console.log(result);
})();`